# Symfony 4 handleRequest run a query

Tags: symfony4

I need help to understand why the `$form->handleRequest($request);` is running some query. I did not find anything about that in the doc.

here is the code that I have simplified as much as possible by removing all unneccessary line and this code is running queries:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/password/reset/confirm/{token}", name="app_user_password_reset_confirm")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     * @param string $token
     * @return Response
     * @throws \Exception 
     */
    public function passwordResetConfirm (Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, string $token) : Response
    {   
        // token cannot be empty. If so exception is thrown
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneBy(['resetRequestToken' => $token]);

        $form = $this->createForm(ResetPasswordFormType::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        return $this->render('security/resetPassword.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

ìn the debugger I can see the query I want, and the query launch by the `handleRequest`:

```
SELECT 
t0.id AS id_1, 
t0.username AS username_2, 
t0.roles AS roles_3, 
t0.password AS password_4, 
t0.email AS email_5, 
t0.reset_request_token AS reset_request_token_6, 
t0.reset_request_token_valid_until AS reset_request_token_valid_until_7, t0.email_address_validation_token AS email_address_validation_token_8, 
t0.email_address_validated_at AS email_address_validated_at_9, 
t0.created_at AS created_at_10, 
t0.updated_at AS updated_at_11 
FROM user t0 
WHERE t0.reset_request_token = 'EOhj0rPG5ffkVTlqO6mDwjThwPEee8nA_Ki8a3TCAa8' 
LIMIT 1;

SELECT 
t0.id AS id_1, 
t0.username AS username_2, 
t0.roles AS roles_3, 
t0.password AS password_4, 
t0.email AS email_5, 
t0.reset_request_token AS reset_request_token_6, 
t0.reset_request_token_valid_until AS reset_request_token_valid_until_7, t0.email_address_validation_token AS email_address_validation_token_8, 
t0.email_address_validated_at AS email_address_validated_at_9, 
t0.created_at AS created_at_10, 
t0.updated_at AS updated_at_11 
FROM user t0 
WHERE t0.username = 'Dudu2020';
```

and both queries are referring the the same entry in the database

```
id_1 : 17
username_2 : Dudu2020
roles_3 : []
password_4 : $2y$13$3STnGc.PQdqdXgPDIw9EKej9A.u9DV5TH7S6TPoLynn...
email_5 : mail@mail.com
reset_request_token_6 : EOhj0rPG5ffkVTlqO6mDwjThwPEee8nA_Ki8a3TCAa8
```

How do I know that is coming form the `handleRequest`? because if I remove it, the second query disappear

I even tried to change first query the parameter to username as the second query do.

Does anybody have a clue to help me to understand?

Answer (score -1):

I finally understood why the handler will run queries and the answer is actually pretty simple... 'validation'.
In my case I had a constraint in the entity for a unique value in the field `Username`
and that is what the handler has verified with query.